# how to fix unassigned shards in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

how to fix unassigned shards in elastic search.
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain"

I have updated the setting in elasticsearch but getting following logs

[2018-06-10T10:35:59,962][DEBUG][o.e.a.a.c.a.TransportClusterAllocationExplainAction] [node-1] explaining the allocation for [ClusterAllocationExplainRequest[useAnyUnassignedShard=true,includeYesDecisions?=false], found shard [[books][4], node[null], [R], recovery_source[peer recovery], s[UNASSIGNED], unassigned_info[[reason=CLUSTER_RECOVERED], at[2018-06-10T05:04:51.465Z], delayed=false, allocation_status[no_attempt]]]

Comment: You have updated what setting?  Since you appear to be running Elasticsearch locally, I assume you are, in essence, running a 1 node cluster.  That means that, if you create indices with the default 5 primary shards and 1 replica (per primary), ES cannot allocate replica shards to the same node as primaries.

Comment: @ryanlutgen yes I am running locally with 5 primary shards and 1 replica, it means when we will deploy in production it will automatically detect. if I want to remove these in locally what I have to ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this blog: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/elasticsearch-unassigned-shards/